# RegEx for multiline search and replace in SQL query code

Tags: sql, regex, search, replace, multiline

There is a lot of qualified documents on the Internet regarding the topic of "search and replace using regular expressions". Only few of them show how to do this in a multiline context. Even fewer show indicate how to generate a regex for several items therein.

I have tried both installable RegEx tools within editors (EditPad Pro, RJ TextED, EmEditor, Notepad++, Sublime Text 3, Visual Studio Professional 2019, the latest JetBrains PHPstorm version, and others) and online RegEx services (regular expressions 101, RegExr) the entire day, read the answers on StackOverflow which corresponded to my title criteria, and additionally tried to make the most of various online tutorials.

You make call me stupid, but I have not been able to understand whether the following concept is feasible at all

The part of the SQL query I want to change is the following one:

```
    AND op.OP1OPVerfahren > 0

    AND p.Testzwecke = 0

    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM ods39.dat_optherapie op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)

    UNION ALL
```

Legend:

- `op.OP1OPVerfahren` is the database field for the first surgery performed, 10 surgical procedures can be documented (`OP1OPVerfahren` until `OP10OPVerfahren`)
- `p.Testzwecke` is a JOIN to the patient's personal data such as first name, last name, etc.
- `ods39.dat_optherapie` is the table `dat_optherapie` from database `ods39` - the system consists of 50 MySQL databases of the exact same structure
- `p.ID` is merely the patient's ID
- `op.revision` is an autoincrementing tracker of how many data record sets for the same surgical procedure have been saved (sometime revisions in the sense of precisions are required)

The above-mentioned part of the query has a quantitative complexity associated: Within the query, this segment appears 780 times in the following variation:

```
    AND **op.OP1OPVerfahren** _up_to_ **op.OP10OPVerfahren** > 0

    AND p.Testzwecke = 0

    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM **ods01.dat_optherapie** _up_to_ **ods39.dat_optherapie** op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)

    UNION ALL
```

To fully understand what I want to solve here the expression I want to replace the fore-mentioned with:

```
    AND **op.OP1OPVerfahren** _up_to_ **op.OP10OPVerfahren** > 0

    AND p.Testzwecke = 0

    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM **ods01.dat_optherapie** _up_to_ **ods39.dat_optherapie** op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)

    GROUP BY **OP1OPVerfahren** _up_to_ **OP10OPVerfahren**

    UNION ALL
```

The `op.OP_x_OPVerfahren` (*x* = 1 to 10) from the very first line and the `OP_x_OPVerfahren` (*x* = 1 to 10) within the `GROUP BY` statement are numerically correlated to each other, i. e. when I want to change my replacing procedure from `op.OP1OPVerfahren` along 39 databases to `op.OP2OPVerfahren` for again 39 databases and so on, the GROUP BY numbers shall change accordingly.

Now, this replacement shall be carried out for all 39 databases. The entire SQL query code is about 20.000 lines of code - my reason why I do not want to spend hours on replacing manually as there are more such SQL query structures in different files which need replacing in a similar fashion.

To give you an example:

The code ...

```
    AND op.OP1OPVerfahren > 0

    AND p.Testzwecke = 0

    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM ods39.dat_optherapie op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)

    UNION ALL
```

... needs to be expanded with a `GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren` before the `UNION ALL` for the 39 databases `ods01` up to `ods39`, accordingly. Then with `op.OP2OPVerfahren` and `OP2OPVerfahren` for the same 39 databases again until `(op.)OP10OPVerfahren` is finally reached (= 780 replacements).

The newly inserted `GROUP BY` statement's `OP_x_...` counting shall have the same number as the `op.OP_x_...` numbering.

I have experimented with tons of different regex statements (such as \d\d, (\d)(\d), \d{2}, and many others according to the individual needs of the above-mentioned editors I used) but I was not able to find out how to make one "number detection" (`op.OP_x_OPVerfahren` and `OP_x_OPVerfahren`) dependent on the "number detection" from the databases `ods_x_.dat_optherapie`).

I would greatly appreciate a bit of help from your most valuable experience and expertise, and I would also be very thankful for receiving further recommendations for other than the mentioned editors with a good (and maybe even testable) regex handling.

Comment: Something along these lines? https://regex101.com/r/0NA6OO/1

Comment: Yes, thank you, it worked like a charm right out of the box. I had to refine it a trifle becuase I had overlooked that there was a small comment right in front of ```ods39``` indicating  the switch to a new ```OP_x_OPVerfahren``` but that was no problem. You saved me loads of tedious hours of manual editing!

Comment: How can I rate your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make this work using a regex replace like this:

```
(AND\ +op\.(OP\d0?OPVerfahren)\ *>\ *0\s+AND\ +p\.Testzwecke\ *=\ *0\s+AND\ +NOT\ +EXISTS\ *\(SELECT\ +DISTINCT\ +1\ +FROM\ +ods[0123][0-9]\.dat_optherapie\ +op2\ +WHERE\ +op2\.patID\ *=\ *p\.ID\ +AND\ +op2\.revision\ *>\ *op\.revision\))(\s+UNION\s+ALL)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NA6OO/1)

It's sticks rather tight to the original string and mostly only introduces variable-length quantifiers for whitespace characters. When there is a `\ *` an optional space may occur, if the space is mandatory `\ +` is used. Otherwise the whitespace shorthand character `\s` is used to allow not only spaces but newlines and alike. To make it work, enable the s|singleline flag (or add `(?s)` in front of the pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the following regex find/replace expressions will do what you are asking:

Find:

`AND op.OP(\d{1,2})(OPVerfahren.*?\))`

Replace with:

`AND op.OP$1$2 \n    GROUP BY OP$1OPVerfahren`

Note that it needs the "global" and "dot matches newline" options set for the regex.

To briefly explain, this has 2 capturing groups, one for the digit(s) between op.OP and OPVerfahren and the second to capture everything after that up to the closing bracket of the "(SELECT DISTINCT... ).  These are then used as $1 and $2 in the replacement section of the regex.

Test example [here](https://regex101.com/r/5YOJnG/21). I believe this should work in Notepad++.

(By the way, I think your "GROUP BY **OP1Verfahren**" should be "GROUP BY **OP1OPVerfahren**" right? i.e. 2 lots of "OP"s!)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right regarding your comment in brackets, I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. After a bit of modifying it, it worked in EditPad Pro.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are happy with the solution, would you care to mark the question as answered?

Comment: I am very grateful to you for having invested your time into looking and trying to solve my problem, but I had to give @wp78de credit for delivering an immediate solution. Thank you again, anyway, please do not consider me to be rude as I have learnt from both of your solutions which I highly appreciate.